# Add event listener change not working for date picker

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a cshtml form with this datepicker:

```html
   <td class="title-4">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Wk_dt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </td>
                    <td class="input-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Wk_dt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control search-form-control date-picker-mon-past-56wk transaction-input", @id = "wkdt" } })


<script src="~/Scripts/PYRL/pyrlDataAdj.js"></script>
```

In my pyrlDataAdj.js:

I am trying to get this event to fire:

```
document.getElementById('wkdt').addEventListener("change", hidehours);
```

to hit this:

```
function hidehours() {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```

All of my other "click" event listeners work:

```
document.getElementById("btnCancel").addEventListener("click", hideConfirm);
document.getElementById("btnFinalSubmit").addEventListener("click", showLoading);
document.getElementById("btnFinalSubmit").addEventListener("click", hideConfirm);
```

I am new to JavaScript and have been trying to figure this out for hours and no dice.

Tried:

```
document.getElementById('wkdt').addEventListener("change", hidehours);
```

to fire:

```
function hidehours() {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```

```
Hidehours()
```

never gets hit

If I change the change to click, it gets hit when I click the input box for the date picker. Something is not working with the "change"

Edit: The "change" event works for the other input fields on my form, just not the datepicker:

```
<td class="title-4">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PTO_hours, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </td>
                    <td class="input-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PTO_hours, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control search-form-control transaction-input", @id = "ptohrs" } })

document.getElementById('ptohrs').addEventListener("change", hidehours);
```

This works. It is just the datepicker field that doesn't hit the hidehours function.

Comment: [The `change` event fires when a user commits a change to an element's value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event). So it may not occur until you've tabbed off the element...

Comment: I change the date in the date picker, then I move on to change the value in another field on my form. Nothing I do on my form leads to hitting the hidehours() function.

Comment: You set the ID twice — once does the helper method itself (it sets ID to `Wk_dt`) and once do you. You'd better delegate that to helper method and use `Wk_dt` in JavaScript.